# Transform chr to date format in R

Tags: r, transform, lubridate

I want to transform from chr to date format
I have this representing year -week:
2020-53
I ve tried to do this

```
 mutate(semana=as_date(year_week,format="%Y-%U"))
```

but I get  the same date in all dataset 2020-01-18

I also tried

```
mutate(semana=strptime(year_week, "%Y-%U"))
```

getting the same result
Here you can see the wrong convertion
[image]
Any idea?, thanks

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? One thing you can try is `rowwise`, though I'm not sure it would resolve the issue

Comment: Try `as.Date(paste0('2020-53','-01'),'%Y-%U-%d')` or `mutate(semana=as.Date(paste0(year_week,'-01'),format="%Y-%U-%d"))`

Comment: It does not work , we must come up with other idea! Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

I think I've got something that does the job.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

# Set up table like example in post
trybble <- tibble(year_week = c("2020-53", rep("2021-01", 5)),
                  country = c("UK", "FR", "GER", "ITA", "SPA", "UK"))

# Function to go into mutate with given info of year and week
y_wsetter <- function(fixme, yeargoal, weekgoal) {
   lubridate::year(fixme) <- yeargoal
   lubridate::week(fixme) <- weekgoal
   return(fixme)
}

# Making a random date so col gets set right
rando <- make_datetime(year = 2021, month = 1, day = 1)

# Show time
trybble <- trybble %>% 
   add_column(semana = rando) %>%  # Set up col of dates to fix
   mutate(yerr = substr(year_week, 1, 4)) %>% # Get year as chr
   mutate(week = substr(year_week, 6, 7)) %>% # Get week as chr
   mutate(semana2 = y_wsetter(semana, 
                              as.numeric(yerr), 
                              as.numeric(week))) %>% # fixed dates
   select(-c(yerr, week, semana))
```

Notes:

- If you somehow plug in a week greater than 53, *lubridate* doesn't mind, and goes forward a year.
- I really struggled to get *mutate* to play nicely without writing my own function *y_wsetter*. In my experience with mutates with multiple inputs, or where I'm changing a "property" of a value instead of the whole value itself, I need to probably write a function. I'm using the *lubridate* package to change just the year or week based on your *year_week* column, so this is one such situation where a quick function helps *mutate* out.
- I was having a weird time when I tried setting *rando* to Sys.Date(), so I manually set it to something using *make_datetime*. YMMV